# How to write this query using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       channel_user_id
FROM communication.interaction_user_status
WHERE channel_user_id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT channel_user_id
                           FROM communication.channel_user 
                           WHERE user_community_id = 1 
                          )
AND status = 0 
GROUP BY channel_user_id;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on the type of configuration you have, usually you cannot include the database name in the query, this must be configured elsewhere

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
       channel_user_id
FROM interaction_user_status
WHERE channel_user_id IN ( SELECT DISTINCT channel_user_id
                           FROM channel_user 
                           WHERE user_community_id = 1 
                          )
AND status = 0 
GROUP BY channel_user_id;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.